Flutter Geolocator.getCurrentPosition() not returning anything
I've been using the Geolocator package for a while and it works good, but for the last 2 days it's not working.
Am trying to get last known position, and if there is none i try to get the current posiotion.
getLastKnownPosition() returns null, and the getCurrentPosition() never finishes and doesn't return anything.
PS: On android emulator and IOS simulator it works fine, but in my android physical device it doesn't work.
Here is my function:
Future<Position> locateUser() async {
  final result = await Geolocator.getLastKnownPosition(
      forceAndroidLocationManager: true);
  if (result != null) {
    return result;
  }
  final result1 = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition();
  return result1;
}

-I have tried uninstalling the app and re-install
-I have tried turning off and on GPS

Try these following points -

Permissions check (if not done).
Add Timeout (Sometimes the network issue and GPS signals are not working).

for e.g. -  final result1 = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition().timeout( Duration(seconds: 10), onTimeout: () { ///you can throw TimeoutException("Location request timed out."); }, );
or you can retry by try and catch and also by 3 retries
like :- `
///try this

    Future<Position> locateUser({int retries = 3}) async {
 
 try {Future<Position> locateUser({int retries = 3}) async {
  try {

    /// Trying to get the last known position of the user
    final result = await Geolocator.getLastKnownPosition(
        forceAndroidLocationManager: true);
    
    /// If we get a valid position
    if (result != null) {
      return result;
    }
    
    /// If no last known position of the user, get the current position of the user with a timeout
    final result1 = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition().timeout(
      Duration(seconds: 10),
      onTimeout: () {
        throw TimeoutException("Location request timed out.");
      },
    );

    return result1;  // Return current position of user if successful
  } catch (e) {
    if (retries > 0) {
      print('Location request failed, retrying... ($retries retries left)');
      await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2)); /// delay Wait before retrying
      return locateUser(retries: retries - 1); /// Retry with reduced count
    } else {
      print("Failed to get location after multiple attempts.");
      rethrow;  /// Throw the error if out of retries
    }
  }
}


Permission is granted. I don't know but after doing some research i found that android will refuse to give permission if it's requested a lot, that's why Geolocator.getCurrentPosition() won't return anything.

Make sure your app has permission to access your locationcheck here
bool serviceEnabled = await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled();
  LocationPermission permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();
  if (!serviceEnabled) {
    // do what you want
  }

  if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
    permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
    if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
      toast('Please location permission');
      logger.w("get User LocationPosition()");
      await Geolocator.openAppSettings();

      throw '${language.lblLocationPermissionDenied}';
    }
  }

